# Regression or naïve Bayes for irregular matrix?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, naive-bayes

I am writing an application to predict exam scores given at least one tuple, where the tuple represents the results of a practice exam:

```
(score, exam_name, date_taken[optional])
```

Users submit practice exam scores and, later, their official exam score (date required); not all users take all available practice exams. The dataset looks like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b & c & d & e & f\\
g\\
h & i & & j\\
k & l & m &&n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
(actual,date)\\
(actual,date)\\ 
(actual,date)\\
(null,date)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Each row represents a `user`. Each column in the first matrix is a particular practice exam; the second matrix is the official score (`actual`) and date taken. Each element in the first matrix is a tuple of the form described above. Users complete an arbitrary combination of practice exams.

The `user` represented by the 4th row has inputted four events (practice exams), the date he plans to take the official exam, but not his actual score; as such, we want to provide him with a prediction.

**What model(s) might be suited for this problem?** Is this question too broad?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I have a hunch that naïve Bayes might be best because of the "incompleteness" of the matrix, and because I want to provide a prediction to the user after *any* input of data (i.e., user inputting a single tuple with no date, `(512, mcat_24)`, should still receive a prediction).

I've also considered a neural network, where each layer processes a tuple. The problem I'm having is not knowing how to even describe this problem.

Comment: This may be more complicated than I anticipated https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03865